Exponential Quantum Speedup for the Traveling Salesman Problem - where is the catch?
Such an article claims that an NP-complete problem can be solved efficiently.
Is it real?
I noticed that they prepare a state $|0\rangle\langle0|+|1\rangle\langle1|$ on an ancilla, which is impossible without using mixed state, which I do not think they use. It is a crucial step in the algorithm, as they use the density matrix of this state to create exponentiation using Density matrix exponentiation.
It should be a noble prize. Where is the catch?

The catch is the parameter $\kappa$, the condition number of the embedding matrix.
I can't comment on the correctness of the whole work. This will require a thorough examination of the content.
But let's assume their claim of runtime $O(N^3log(N)\kappa/\epsilon + 1/{\epsilon}^3)$ is correct. Still, this is insufficient to prove that the Travelling salesman problem lies in BQP.
This is due to the appearance of $\kappa$ in the runtime expression. There is no control on how $\kappa$ scales as input $N$. For some problems, the dependency of the $\kappa$ with $N$ might scale exponentially. The parameter $\kappa$ looks innocent but hides a strong assumption that could make the overall runtime superpolynomial. That's why they haven't claimed to prove NP-complete problems lie in BQP (in the paper).
To build the intuition for how matrix condition number plays their role in quantum algorithms runtime, one of the best ways to start is to analyse Quantum Linear System algorithms (like HHL) and their dependency on $\kappa$. It reveals how the quantum speedups are restricted to certain types of matrices. We often see the term 'well-conditioned matrix' in this context.

Addendum: I do recall our instructor fooled us for a while with the dynamic programming algorithm for the knapsack (an NP-complete) problem. It seems to us that a polynomial time algorithm exists for it. But later, he revealed the catch. The parameter $W$ played the same role as $\kappa$ is doing here. Such algorithms have a self-explanatory name called pseudo-polynomial algorithms.

Thank you, can you please explain more what kappa is, I did not fully understood it - what is it describing?

@RonCohen. As per definition, for normal matrices, condition number $\kappa$ is the ratio of largest to lowest eigenvalue. One of the key steps in the paper is to rotate state |0> by an angle $1/{\kappa}$. (page 3, last two paragraphs). Thus, such kappa-dependent steps in the algorithm can be easy in some cases/matrices and hard in some other cases. One can always cook up a problem where the kappa of the matrix is not so easy (polynomial number of steps) to implement.

The authors claim in their last update that $\kappa$ is polynomial in $N$. I haven't in any way checked this claim, I just wanted to let you know if you want to take a look at it!

@TristanNemoz, I am reviewing it. They seems (in the last paragraph )to recognize that the worst case scenario for superpolynomial scaling of condition number could happen in principle. Thus theoretically it is possible to come up with such hard instances for TSP.
